# Simple example of using Collectors with java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Imagine I have a file like:

```
1, Apple
1, Pear
1, Orange
2, Apple
3, Melon
3, Orange
```

I want to parse this into a list with each entry being a map or I guess it could be my own object but I thought a map would be best as it is a key. value.

I was trying:

```
private List<Map<String, String>> readRecords(String path) {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
            .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(SEPARATOR)))
            .map(snippets -> new HashMap<Integer, String>().put(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But this gives me a error about not being able to convert between `List<String>` and `List<Map<String, String>>`

Or perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't your method return a `List<Map<Integer, String>>`?

Comment: As an aside, I'd omit the `Arrays.asList()` call, as it just adds clutter.

Comment: I would think what you want is a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` based on the file.  It looks like you have a 1-to-many mapping.  For instance, from your file, I read it as "1" maps to "Apple, Pear, Orange."

Answer (score 5):

Besides the return type not being correct (`List<Map<Integer, String>>`), the `put` method will give you the previous value mapped if any.

So

```
.map(snippets -> new HashMap<Integer, String>().put(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1)))
```

is actually a mapping `List<String> -> String` and not `List<String> -> Map<Integer, String>`.

If you want to stick with the official API, I would return a `List<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>>` instead as each line represents a key-value pair and change the `map` call to:

```
.map(snippets -> new SimpleEntry<>(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1)))
```

... or collect the entire content into a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (look at the `groupingBy` collector).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is this line:

```
snippets -> new HashMap<Integer, String>().put(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1))
```

The return type of this lambda is `String` because `Map.put(key,value)` returns not the map itself but `value`.

*Apart from this, I'm not quite sure using a fully fledged, mutable hash map for storing a single key-value pair is justifiable. I'd probably collect the value pairs into a single map rather than a list of single-entry maps.*

---

Another problem spotted by Eran is that your method should return `List<Map<Integer,String>>` and not `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You should return a created map from the second `map` lambda:

```
private List<Map<Integer, String>> readRecords(String path) {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
            .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(SEPARATOR)))
            .map(snippets -> {
                Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                map.put(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1));
                return map; 
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As your maps contain only single mapping, it's better to use `singletonMap` though:

```
private List<Map<Integer, String>> readRecords(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
        .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(SEPARATOR)))
        .map(snippets -> Collections.singletonMap(Integer.parseInt(snippets.get(0)), snippets.get(1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess using a map here is an overkill. You can look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html

Comment: You should explain how to use `Pair` in this situation and why it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comment I made to the original post, this is the code I came up with.  Obviously it assumes you *do* want have a 1-to-many relationship, with an integer mapped to a `List<String>`.

```
public class MappingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MappingDemo demo = new MappingDemo();
        System.out.println("... Using custom collector ...");
        demo.dumpMap(demo.getFruitMappingsWithCustomCollector());
        System.out.println("... Using 'External' map ...");
        demo.dumpMap(demo.getFruitMappingsWithExternalMap());
    }

    public Map<Integer, List<String>> getFruitMappingsWithCustomCollector(){
        // Resulting map is created from within the lambda expression.
        return getContent().stream().map(s -> s.split(",\\s"))
                .collect(
                      HashMap::new,
                      (map, ary) -> map.computeIfAbsent(Integer.parseInt(ary[0]),
                            k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(ary[1]),
                      (map1, map2) -> map1.entrySet().addAll(map2.entrySet())
                );
    }

    public Map<Integer,List<String>> getFruitMappingsWithExternalMap(){
        // Create the map external from the lambda and add to it.
        final Map<Integer,List<String>> fruitMappings = new HashMap<>();
        getContent().stream().map(s -> s.split(",\\s"))
              .forEach(ary ->
                    fruitMappings.computeIfAbsent(Integer.parseInt(ary[0]),
                          k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(ary[1]));
        return fruitMappings;
    }

    public void dumpMap(Map<Integer,List<String>> map){
        map.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()));
    }

    public List<String> getContent(){
        return Arrays.asList("1, Apple",
              "1, Pear",
              "1, Orange",
              "2, Apple",
              "3, Melon",
              "3, Orange",
              "1, Mango",
              "3, Star Fruit",
              "4, Pineapple",
              "2, Pomegranate");
    }
}
```

And the output

```
... Using custom collector ...
1 -> [Apple, Pear, Orange, Mango]
2 -> [Apple, Pomegranate]
3 -> [Melon, Orange, Star Fruit]
4 -> [Pineapple]
... Using 'External' map ...
1 -> [Apple, Pear, Orange, Mango]
2 -> [Apple, Pomegranate]
3 -> [Melon, Orange, Star Fruit]
4 -> [Pineapple]
```

I'm quite sure someone can do better.

`getContent` was a just a simple means for getting the values using the text you gave.  It would be just as easy to use [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) in place of `getContent()` if you are actually reading a `File`.